# How to Expand a property in a variable

Tags: powershell

if I go

```
$c = Resolve-DnsName facebook.com -Type TXT -Server '8.8.8.8'
```

When I enter `$c` I get

```
Name                                     Type   TTL   Section    Strings
----                                     ----   ---   -------    -------
facebook.com                             TXT    7200  Answer     {v=spf1 redirect=_spf.facebook.com}        
facebook.com                             TXT    7200  Answer     {google-site-verification=A2WZWCNQHrGV_TW  
                                                                 wKh6KHY90tY0SHZo_RnyMJoDaG0s}
facebook.com                             TXT    7200  Answer     {google-site-verification=wdH5DTJTc9AYNwV  
                                                                 unSVFeK0hYDGUIEOGb-RReU6pJlY}
```

How do I expand `$c.strings` ?

I know I can get the expanded strings and lose the rest with

```
Resolve-DnsName facebook.com -Type TXT -Server '8.8.8.8' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty strings
```

How do I get the entire answer expanded ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.1#example-11--create-calculated-properties-for-each-inputobject) to redefine the **Strings property** from `string[]` to `string`:

```bash
Resolve-DnsName google.com -Type TXT -Server '8.8.8.8' |
    Select-Object Name, Type, TTL, Section, @{ N = 'Strings'; E = { [string] $_.Strings }} |
        Format-Table
```

This would result in:

```bash
Name         Type    TTL   Section   Strings           
----         ----    ---   -------   -------           
google.com    TXT   3600    Answer   docusign=05958488-....
google.com    TXT   3600    Answer   google-site-verifi....
google.com    TXT   3600    Answer   docusign=1b0a6754-....
google.com    TXT   3600    Answer   google-site-verifi....
google.com    TXT   3600    Answer   globalsign-smime-d....
google.com    TXT   3600    Answer   MS=E4A68B9AB2BB967....
google.com    TXT   3600    Answer   apple-domain-verif....
google.com    TXT   3600    Answer   v=spf1 include:_sp....
google.com    TXT   3600    Answer   facebook-domain-ve....
```

If there where more than one string in the Strings property, using above code would join the strings with [`$OFS` (Out Field Separator)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables?view=powershell-7.2#ofs), **by default a space**:

```bash
Name         Type    TTL   Section   Strings
----         ----    ---   -------   -------
google.com    TXT   3339    Answer   docusign=4752-4e...   docusign=4752-4e...
```

---

If you want a ***multi-line string*** instead, you could use [`Out-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-string?view=powershell-7.1), however that would require first to [`.Trim()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trim?view=net-6.0) the output and also use `-Wrap` on [`Format-Table`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table?view=powershell-7.2) to be displayed correctly.

An example of how the code would look like using a hardcoded value (**`docusign=05958488`**):

```bash
Resolve-DnsName google.com -Type TXT -Server '8.8.8.8' |
    Select-Object Name, Type, TTL, Section, @{
        Name       = 'Strings'
        Expression = { ('docusign=05958488', 'docusign=05958488' | Out-String).Trim() }
    } | Format-Table -Wrap
```

You could also use the [`-join` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.1#split-and-join-operators) to concatenate the strings with a `CRLF` (`` `r`n ``) to get a *multi-line string*:

```bash
Resolve-DnsName google.com -Type TXT -Server '8.8.8.8' |
    Select-Object Name, Type, TTL, Section, @{
        Name       = 'Strings'
        Expression = { 'docusign=05958488', 'docusign=05958488' -join "`r`n" }
    } | Format-Table -Wrap
```

Both examples result in:

```bash
Name         Type    TTL   Section   Strings
----         ----    ---   -------   -------
google.com    TXT   3574    Answer   docusign=05958488
                                     docusign=05958488
google.com    TXT   3574    Answer   docusign=05958488
                                     docusign=05958488
google.com    TXT   3574    Answer   docusign=05958488
                                     docusign=05958488
```

---

If you want a solution that could handle both cases, **Strings** having only one value and **Strings** having multiple values, you could use something like this:

```bash
$result = Resolve-DnsName google.com -Type TXT -Server '8.8.8.8'
# Add random values to Strings for testing
$result.ForEach({ $_.Strings += Get-Random })
# Code logic
$result = foreach($element in $result) {
    $out = [ordered]@{
        Name    = $element.Name
        Type    = $element.Type
        TTL     = $element.TTL
        Section = $element.Section
    }

    foreach($e in $element.Strings) {
        $out.Strings = $e
        # output one object per string
        [pscustomobject] $out
    }
}

$result | Format-Table
```

Above logic would be creating a new object **per element in the Strings property**. The output would be:

```bash
TTL   Section  Name       Type   Strings
---   -------  ----       ----   -------
3444  Answer   google.com  TXT   apple-domain-verificatio...
3444  Answer   google.com  TXT   1419241945              
3444  Answer   google.com  TXT   MS=E4A68B9AB2BB9670BCE15...
3444  Answer   google.com  TXT   463070462               
3444  Answer   google.com  TXT   facebook-domain-verifica...
3444  Answer   google.com  TXT   958788674               
3444  Answer   google.com  TXT   google-site-verification...
3444  Answer   google.com  TXT   1623605637
```